# What might cause long last_optimize_duration times on a simple query in SQL Server (Azure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization

Occassionaly, SQL Azure will cause a simple query inside of a stored procedure to take a long time to run.  After much research, I've tracked the issue down to the last_optimize_duration within query store showing 20+ seconds.

I've re-written the query in a number of ways, simplified it, used a with index, tried calling other stored procs from the main one. The query itself seems to run fast 100% of the time EXCEPT sometimes when the system recompiles it. Of course if I do it within SSMS it compiles and runs quickly.

```
CREATE PROC[dbo].spLogHatesMe(
    @CID[VARCHAR](200),
    @LogType VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)

AS
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Log
WHERE CID = @CID
AND LogType = @LogType;
GO
```

Also Note that the Log table has an Index on CID and LogType.

I would expect the optimization time to be similar to all other compilations in the 1000-5000 microsecond range.  Not '25913462' which was the last duration I had.  No other queries are having the same type of issue.

The Log table is a log table that is mostly inserts. For one specific task we need to look back at and read one of the values.  Roughly, 20-25 inserts per 1 read.

I'm using this query out of the query store to get the compile times:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM   sys.query_store_plan AS Pl
       INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query AS Qry ON Pl.query_id = Qry.query_id
       INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query_text AS Txt ON Qry.query_text_id = Txt.query_text_id
WHERE Qry.is_internal_query=0
ORDER BY Pl.last_compile_start_time desc
```

Comment: My first guess would be that the long compilations are where it needed to update statistics on one or more columns

Comment: @MartinSmith  using sys.dm_db_stats_properties and checking the times vs the sys.query_store* values it looks like the stats were updated about an hour before the query issue.  I may not be looking at it properly though.

Comment: @DavidMack But queries aren't recompiled when stats are updated. They're *marked for recompile* and that doesn't happen until the next time the query runs. You can't use stats properties to determine when the recompile happened.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, and Martin Smith, I was looking at the time stamps wrong (damn UTC).  the update for the stat and the compile time for the stored proc are about the same times: Compile: 13:39:42 vs  Stats:13:40:08 which is a 26 second difference, which is about equal to the delay time I experienced.    Question then is, how do I fix it?  Should I just disable auto update stats on that table?

Answer (score 0):

After much research, turns out Azure was indeed updating before executing the stored procedure.

I used SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON   to make that into an async operation instead.

Once I did that, the errors I was getting completely stopped.  Haven't had the same issue since, and that was months ago.